# Add thumbnails in 'li' list

Tags: list

I'm new to WP so I'm still finding my way around.

I want to create a simple list of thumbnails. In html I have done this like so

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="images/personal01.jpg"><img src="images/personal01.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/personal03.jpg"><img src="images/personal03.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/personal04.jpg"><img src="images/personal04.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/personal05.jpg"><img src="images/personal05.jpg" /></a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
```

In WP I have simply added thumbnails to a page with Upload/Insert and picked thumbnail from the Add Media window.

I have used this php to add the content to the page

```
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <nav>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    </nav>  

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This outputs code like this, each img is wrapped in an "p" tag

```
    <nav>

            <p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal14.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-32" title="personal14" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal14-221x150.jpg" alt="" width="221" height="150" /></a></p>
    <p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal13.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-31" title="personal13" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal13-199x150.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="150" /></a></p>
    <p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal12.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-30" title="personal12" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal12-199x150.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="150" /></a></p>

        </nav>
```

Is it possible to surround each img width a "li" tag instead of a "p" tag so it's like the original html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a post loop can't you just put your images in li's within the editor. Just select them and put them into a bulleted list.

Comment: oH I didn't realise you could put them into a bullet list like that - that's that sorted then, thanks